# Test which browser a WebExtension is running in

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to show some text on the option page which depends on whether my extension is running in Firefox or Chrome (namely, a warning that there is a relevant bug in Firefox and which version it's fixed in). What is the best way to test for it?

Comment: If `window.browser` is defined it's Firefox where you can use browser.runtime.getBrowserInfo(). If `chrome.app` is defined, it's Chrome where you can parse navigator.userAgent to get the version.

Comment: With `browser-polyfill`, `window.browser` will be defined in Chrome too. I'll need to check what happens with `browser.runtime.getBrowserInfo()` there when I test on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I check.

```
// Hide option for Chrome
let isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') !== -1;
if (!isFirefox) {
    document.getElementById('CP_l').style.display = "none";
}
```